# Question voted to be closed and no comment

Tags: discussion

I found [this question](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/12520/layering-multiple-chess-games) that had been downvoted twice and had two votes for closing for not being clear. However, there was no comment left in the question asking the OP what they meant or trying to help.

I should say that having an answer downvoted without knowing the reason can be quite annoying and frustrating for the asker. So, since we don't want to downvote newbies away (do we?) I suggest leaving a helpful comment/constructive critique when downvoting and/or voting for closure.